# Anonymous arrow function with anonymous object in razor component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, arrow-functions

I have a razor page. and I want to add an external javascript, this javascript uses an anonymous object as param and is an anonymous arrow function (if I not wrong)

> `()=>{......}();`

if I set this javascript in plain html, I can write as:

```
<script src="https://externalsite.foo/bar/js/external.js">
{
 "blah": [
   "somedata": "somevalue",
   "somedata": "somevalue"
 ],
 "someotherdata": "someothervalue"
}
</script>
```

I think I need to use IJSRuntime. but InvokeAsync and InvokeVoidAsync needs to send the function name. I saw another examples with "import" and "eval".
In the "import" example, it not use anonymous arrow function.
In the "eval" example the code is local, not in an external place.

Thank you for your help!